# JQuery $.post 500 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to do $.post call but I keep getting a 500 error and I dont know why,

```
$http.post('/api/report/action/post', JSON.stringify($scope.user))
            .success(function (data) {
                alert('sucess');
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                alert('error');
            });
```

the url is correct, is there something wrong with the way I am passing in the data?

Comment: We'd need more info, it depends where you are posting it. It could be that the api you are using gives a 500 error if not authenticated etc

Comment: yes, why are you using JSON.stringify ? Is `$scope.user`  an object? Inspect the actual request in browser console to see what is being sent. More importantly 500 is server error so debug server code also

Comment: Seems like a great job for `ngResource` - could simply call `$scope.user.$save`

Comment: Usually means something is wrong with the code server side (the code that is accepting the post).  If it's MVC, looks like something it is expecting might be null

Comment: Have you opened url directly in browser?

Comment: A 500 error is server side, this code has no relevance other than the value of `JSON.stringify($scope.user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 500 is an error on server side.

It usually states that the code that is executed by your call to /api/report/action/post has failed.

It could fail for a lot of thing, of course. Maybe you are passing the wrong parameters, or in the wrong encoding. Or maybe just it has a bug.

The steps I'd take to debug this would be:

1) Check what happens when I execute the call directly. Is there an error? Do this error throws more light about the problem?

2) If there is no error calling the method directly I'd check if my call is correct. Am I passing the correct url? And the correct parameters? Is the data being passed the expected data? It's encoding as the server expects it?

3) If the direct call works and my remote call seems to be correct I'd try to use a tool like fiddler to check all the steps and data in the call/response data transmission, and try to detect where things get tricky.

Hope it helps.